# Check if given string is Built In data Type Name, which are aliases of predefined types in the System Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net

How to find if given string is Built In Types, which are aliases of predefined types in the System Namespace.
Ex: 1

```
Input = "System.Int32" (this is string)
OutPut : True(indicating it's Built-In Name)
```

Ex :2

```
Input = "xxx"
Output = False(indicating it's not Built-In Type name)
```

Any suggestion regarding this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you define as "built-in"? Does any framework class count, or are you limiting it to "Those defined in mscorlib" or something like that? What does `ado.net` have to do with this question? Please explain your problem, and your requirements better.

Comment: @RB.: sorry i referred built in types to "c# predefined types"

Comment: @cHao I think the question means things like built in .NET value types such as `string`, `int`, `double`, `bool` but their Type names as apose to the types themselves

Comment: @sandeep: C# "predefined types" are just aliases for the real types.  The framework isn't going to have a way (outside the C# compiler namespaces) to know whether a type has some alias in some specific language.  You'll more than likely need to check manually.

Comment: @Luke: I was kinda getting that, but second-guessed myself and deleted the comment.  Turns out the question was about 90% what i thought it was.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public bool IsBuiltInType(string typeName)
{
  return Type.GetType(typeName, false) != null; 
}
```

I think this is what your looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx

```
  IsBuiltInType("System.Int32");
```

The above returns true, as it finds the System.Int32 type - You can also throw an error if it doesn't find the specified type.

Comment: This also returns true for other types that are currently loaded, including user-defined classes. For example `"MyProjectName.MySubNamespace.SomeClassByMyself"` might return `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to check if a type-name belongs to a sql-type.  There's  no property or method available in the framework.

But you can do what `SqlParameter` [would do to infer conversion](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid8042FEB31BBB16B0DF17807B715D72930F82C722.aspx) from `Type` to `SqlDbType` if it's not set explicitely.

Following method is directly derived  from SqlParameter's `InferSqlType`:

```
public static bool IsConvertibleToSqlDbType(String type)
{
    switch(type) {
        case "System.Int64":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt64":
            return true;
        case "System.Boolean":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBoolean":
            return true;
        case "System.String":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlString":
            return true;
        case "System.DateTime":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime":
            return true;
        case "System.Decimal":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDecimal":
            return true;
        case "System.Double":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDouble":
            return true;
        case "System.Byte[]":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlBinary":
            return true;
        case "System.Byte":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlByte":
            return true;
        case "System.Int32":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32":
            return true;
        case "System.Single":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.Single":
            return true;
        case "System.Int16":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt16":
            return true;
        case "System.Guid":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid":
            return true;
        case "System.Money":
        case "System.SmallMoney":
        case "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlMoney":
            return true;
        case "System.Object":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for Assembly.GetType(string)

If the method returns null, the assembly does not know the type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettype.aspx

Then you would only need to know which assembly you want to check against.

<strike>In your case, it looks like the System assembly would suffice.</strike>

Jeppe makes a good point, see his comment below.

Comment: He **could** use the `System.dll` assembly, but I think he would want the `mscorlib.dll` assembly. This is where the fundamental types are defined. He could get a reference to this assembly with `var assembly = typeof(object).Assembly;`.

Answer (score 1):

`Type.GetType("System.Int32", false) != null` would let you know if the type exists. But, it would also check for types loaded in current app domain.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
static class TypeHelper
{
  public static readonly IList<string> BuiltInTypeNames;

  static TypeHelper()
  {
    Type[] allBuiltInTypes = { typeof(string), typeof(int), typeof(decimal), }; // add whatever types you consider "built-in".
    BuiltInTypeNames = allBuiltInTypes.Select(t => t.FullName).ToList().AsReadOnly();
  }
}
```

Then with an input string `input` you can say `TypeHelper.BuiltInTypeNames.Contains(input)` to get the boolean (true/false value) you want.